# java string.getIndex correct index ignoring punctuation

Tags: java

If I had a string like this one that has punctuation like `,, ?, ;,`, what if I wanted to use `string.indexOf();` to search for a string such as "`like`", and get back the index?

If I remove all punctuation I could search it but because of the punctuation earlier it would give me the wrong index in the string. Is there a built-in way in Java to do such a thing? I have a workaround in mind I am going to test but won't bother if there's a proper way.

Comment: Are you looking for something like wildcard or regular expression matching?

Comment: Please post specific examples of the search and target strings.

Comment: Can't you simply use String.indexOf(), get the index, and then run another loop over the string to subtract the number of punctuation marks?

Comment: I am doing this for an android app. I am using an sqlite database with FTS3 to search long strings but when I display the results it obviously print the the text in a text view from the beginning even if the matching text is farther along in the string. I wrote my own custom display class and want to use a substring to chop the beginning of the larger string so that the matching text displays near the beginning of the textview. 

So I want to use a indexof call to find the spot in the string but I dont want the user to have to worry about entering punctuation.

Comment: So for instance if I had

"so, for, instance, if, I, had."

and I searched "if I" I would want to get an index of 20 and not 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is! It is called [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Build a regex matching your punctuation and seeked substring, and search for it.

You might want to also have a look at the [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) classes.